# How to connect oracle database that is accessible from remote desktop in local machine using python?

Tags: python, database, remote-desktop, cx-oracle

Detail about question:

I use following step to connect oracle from local machine.

1. connect to remote desktop by ip(xx.xx.xxx.xxx) and username-password
2. open sql developer and connect to database using hostname, port, SID/service name and username-password.

Can I do this task from local machine itself using python?

Note: I am able to connect to databases that are accessible from local machine using cx_oracle.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It sounds like you want to invoke SQL Developer from Python? What exactly do you want to do with your data?

Comment: @Christopher I want to access the database from local machine using python. I have access permission only through remote desktop. Is there any way? So I can connect to remote desktop then database using python?

Comment: Your "Note:" made it seem like you'd already done that.  Just install the Python cx_Oracle module and, if necessary, Oracle client libraries.  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html  Or do you have problems with the connect string?  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html Please update your question with more detail.

Comment: Yes, i cam able to connect databases from local machine using cx_oracle which are accessible from local machine. But, my question is that how to connect to database that is accessible from remote desktop only.

Comment: The question is: what do you want to do?  Are you running batch scripts, web services or what?  Fundamentally you'll need to start something on a machine that can access the DB.

Comment: i want run a query on that DB using cx_Oracle from local machine. But issue is i have access for that DB only on remote desktop. So i want to connect it first then run query on that DB....More details lets say ABC is a database which is accessible from my remote desktop whose ip is xx.xx.xxx.xxx. But i want to run a query on ABC from my local machine  where i have installed python.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall on the DB machine maybe set to allow Remote Desktop Protocol only.  Please check the firewall setting on the DB machine.